# Minecraft Spectator mode invisibility glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been working on a Minecraft custom pet with an invisible dog and an armor stand and one time I was using spectator mode to check if the dog was sitting and when I went back to creative the dog was translucent and visible. I restarted my game and even my computer and nothing works.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried viewing the dog in survival or adventure mode?

Comment: oh, i Actually haven't thought of that.

Comment: Viewing the dog in survival or adventure mode didn't work but thanks alot.

Comment: Are you in the same 'team' as the dog perhaps?

Comment: I left the team and it worked! Thank you so much D-Inventor!

Comment: I converted my suggestion to an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So because you are on the same team as the dog, you are able to see him even though he's invisible. There are 2 things that you can do:

- leave the dog's team
- set the team option `seeFriendlyInvisibles` to false

`/scoreboard teams option TEAMNAME seeFriendlyInvisibles false`